# add icons to tabs in ownerdrawfixed

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Trying to get a solution for this. Here I'm simply adding icons to tabs in the TabControl. DrawMode is changed to **OwnerDrawFixed**.

Here's what I've tried so far in the **DrawITem** event of TabControl:

```
Dim tab_rect As Rectangle = TabControl1.GetTabRect(e.Index)
Dim TAB_MARGIN As Integer = 3

Dim layout_rect As New RectangleF( _
       tab_rect.Left + TAB_MARGIN, _
       tab_rect.Y + TAB_MARGIN, _
       tab_rect.Width - 4 * TAB_MARGIN, _
       tab_rect.Height - 2 * TAB_MARGIN)
```

So as to add the icon, I use :

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.airline, layout_rect.Right - 90, layout_rect.Left)
```

However, the code works fine and the image is added. 
But the image for one tab disappears when i switch to another tab.Why should this be happening?

Any alternate idea for the same purpose is welcome.

Okay, for the purpose of troubleshoot, I'm adding the entire code for TabControl_DrawItem event. Here goes the one :

```
Private Sub TabControl1_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.DrawItem

    'Firstly we'll define some parameters.
    Dim CurrentTab As TabPage = TabControl1.TabPages(e.Index)
    Dim ItemRect As Rectangle = TabControl1.GetTabRect(e.Index)
    Dim FillBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(224, 229, 249))
    Dim TextBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
    Dim sf As New StringFormat
    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
    sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center

    'If we are currently painting the   TabItem we'll 
    'change the brush colors and inflate the rectangle.
    If CBool(e.State And DrawItemState.Selected) Then
        FillBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(224, 229, 249)
        TextBrush.Color = Color.Black
        ItemRect.Inflate(2, 2)
    End If

    'Set up rotation for left and right aligned tabs
    If TabControl1.Alignment = TabAlignment.Left Or TabControl1.Alignment = TabAlignment.Right Then
        Dim RotateAngle As Single = 90
        If TabControl1.Alignment = TabAlignment.Left Then RotateAngle = 270
        Dim cp As New PointF(ItemRect.Left + (ItemRect.Width \ 2), ItemRect.Top + (ItemRect.Height \ 2))
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(cp.X, cp.Y)
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(RotateAngle)
        ItemRect = New Rectangle(-(ItemRect.Height \ 2), -(ItemRect.Width \ 2), ItemRect.Height, ItemRect.Width)
    End If

    'Next we'll paint the TabItem with our Fill Brush
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(FillBrush, ItemRect)

    Dim tab_rect As Rectangle = TabControl1.GetTabRect(e.Index)

    Dim layout_rect As New RectangleF( _
       tab_rect.Left + TAB_MARGIN, _
      tab_rect.Y + TAB_MARGIN, _
     tab_rect.Width - 4 * TAB_MARGIN, _
    tab_rect.Height - 2 * TAB_MARGIN)
 e.Graphics.DrawString(CurrentTab.Text, e.Font, TextBrush, RectangleF.op_Implicit(ItemRect), sf)
    '



'Here I add Images for each tab header
e.Graphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.airline, layout_rect.Left, layout_rect.Left, 20, 20)



    e.Graphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.hotel, layout_rect.Right + 15, layout_rect.Left - 1, 20, 20)



    e.Graphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.insurance, layout_rect.Right + 82, layout_rect.Left - 1, 20, 20)
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.rail, layout_rect.Right + 177, layout_rect.Left - 2, 20, 20)
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.tour, layout_rect.Right + 240, layout_rect.Left - 2, 20, 20)
    '
    'End If


    'Reset any Graphics rotation
    e.Graphics.ResetTransform()

    'Finally, we should Dispose of our brushes.
    FillBrush.Dispose()
    TextBrush.Dispose()

End Sub
```

Comment: Hard to guess why you see anything at all.  Instead of layout_rect.Left use the Top property instead.

Comment: What are your tab dimensions?  `layout_rect.Right - 90` seems kind of a large swath from the right side.Why aren't you measuring from the left?  Is the SizeMode Fixed?

Comment: Clarification : Images do appear when the form loads (or when the app runs). The real problem comes when i select a tab, its corresponding icon image disappears (or hides?) and only the tab header text remains. Please look into the code I attached for TabControl_DrawItem event.